# Is there a way to get each value from entry.Collection in ef code first?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity

I currently have the following code:

```
 System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] names = _entity.GetType().GetProperties();
            var entry = this.Entry(_entity);
            foreach (var property in names)
            {
                var m = entry.Member(property.Name);
                if (m is DbPropertyEntry)//simple property
                {
                    var p = entry.Property(property.Name);
                    currentVal.Add(p.CurrentValue.ToString());
                }
                if (m is DbReferenceEntry)//navigation to single object
                {
                    var r = entry.Reference(property.Name);
                    currentVal.Add(r.CurrentValue.ToString());
                }
                if (m is DbCollectionEntry)//navigation to collection
                {
                    var c = entry.Collection(property.Name);
                    currentVal.Add(c.CurrentValue.ToString());               
                }
            }
```

I would like to get each field value from the collection associated with my entity but the entry.Collection(property.Name) only returns the collection name not the fields within that collection such as its name, id etc.. therefore I cannot actually get the current values within the collection.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Edit:

Entity I'm working with is set up like so:

```
 public class Project
    {

        public int Id { get; set; } // PK
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int MarketId { get; set; } // FK
        [ForeignKey("MarketId")]
        public Market Market { get; set; } // FK Nav   
        public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } // Many to Many Nav 
    }
```

The collection in question I wish to view is the Teams, I am carrying out auditing for this entity and when a new project is created I want to see the updated values for the associated project id in the teams table

Comment: what is `currentVal`? you even want to add strings of all fields in the `entry.Collection`? that's a strange requirement.

Comment: Hi currentVal is a list for storing the current values, for example the entry.Property will have an Id with currentVal 2, Name with currentVal test etc... I want the same information from the collection associated with this entity but I cannot seem to extract this in the same way.

I should have mentioned this is for auditing purposes, I need to see changes made with this entity along with the changes in its collection which is a one to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to loop through the items in your entity's collections. One approach would be to cast c.CurrentValue to IEnumerable and then to use foreach to loop through the enumerable.

```
foreach(var x in (IEnumerable) c.CurrentValue){
  // do something with the entity here
}
```

That would give you the entities in the collection. Depending on what you want to do with them you could ToString() the entities themselves or recursively use the code you posted to get at their property values.

One thing to be aware of is that EF does not eagerly load collection properties. So it could be that the collection is empty in memory while it is not empty in the DB. The DbCollectionEntry type has an IsLoaded property to check this.

Comment: Hi I've tried using foreach it still does not give me any values the only information I can extract is the long collection name whereas in the locals window I can clearly see each field in the collection model and its values for each.

Comment: c.CurrentValue.ToString() gives me something like this: System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[EntityType]. This is a collection of entities. Using foreach gives me each entity (or rather a dynamic proxy) that looks like this {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EntityType_BLABLA. This is an instance of one entity in the collection. I'm not sure it makes sense to get the properties of the entities in the collection.

Comment: I have updated the question above to show the entity im working with and why I would like the values of the collection associated

Comment: I'm not sure you are heading in the right direction with your design. Although that is hard to say without knowing more about your requirements at a higher level. If you want the values of the related teams then you could `foreach` through the teams in the collection and then use code similar to your original code to get at their property values. But, again,  my feeling is that you should review your design first. Sorry I haven't been more help.

Comment: Hi I got it working with a foreach and using the above code to extract the values, its not a great design I'm only a recent graduate! Thanks for your suggestion it pushed me in the right direction

Comment: Would you give me an upvote then. I really need the rep :-).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you want to make a `Select` based on an array of strings, which are the properties' names. Am I right?.

Have you tried to use Linq Dynamic? http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/. It allows you to construct LINQ queries using string expressions.

```
var result = myQuery
    .Select("new (Field1, Field2)");

//in your case
 var result2 = myQuery
    .Select("new (" + string.Join(fields, ', ') + ")");
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Hi, yes I want to select the property names from the collection and get their current values. I'm not sure where the fields comes from in your anser?